# How can I compare Sheet A with Sheet B and add new cells to Sheet B?

Tags: javascript

first of all I need to say that I do not have any experience in programming. I tried to wrap my head around JavaScript in the course of the last 7 days and although I find the world that opens up through programming really fascinating, I did not get past a very, very rough general understanding.

**What I have so far:**
I´m currently working on a Google Sheet that automatically imports JSON data out of a list from a webpage. The import of the JSON data works fine und the result is a Google Sheet with 100 cells and 13 columns after the JSON-Import that gets updated every minute through a Timer.

**What my problem is:**
The list on the webpage I´m scraping my data from contains only 100 cells (never more then 100 cells). So when new data is fed in the list of the webpage, older entries just vanish out of the list and make space for newer entries. This leads to the situation that with every JSON import I do, only the most recent 100 cells will be imported, although I still want to keep the old cells in my Google Sheet that are not shown on the webpage anymore.
Basically I´m looking for a script that extracts the most recent JSON import from my main sheet (Name:"TXs") into a new sheet (Name:Convert). "Convert" should then be constantly compared to "TXs" if new values have been added/scraped. What will happen is that after some time the list of the most recent JSON Imports in "TXs" will contain cells that are not yet updated in "Convert" and cells that vanished/made space in "TXs" that are still present in "Convert".

---

Webpage Scrapes in "TXs" before cell update on webpage:

| Type | Result balance | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ADDRESS D | 3947 | ... |
| ADDRESS C | 9386 | ... |
| ADDRESS B | 9286 | ... |
| ADDRESS A | 1837 | ... |

Webpage Scrapes in "TXs" after cell update on webpage:

| Type | Result balance | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ADDRESS E | 1456 | ... |
| ADDRESS D | 3947 | ... |
| ADDRESS C | 9386 | ... |
| ADDRESS B | 9286 | ... |

---

While Address E is a new cell that got updated on the page, Address A is now missing and not listed anymore.

Sheet "Convert" however should contain ALL the information, even the Addresses that are not present anymore on the webpage:

---

Sheet "Convert" after running the script:

| Type | Result balance | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ADDRESS E | 1456 | ... |
| ADDRESS D | 3947 | ... |
| ADDRESS C | 9386 | ... |
| ADDRESS B | 9286 | ... |
| ADDRESS A | 1837 | ... |

---

**What I´ve tried so far:**
I experimented a bit with the code someone provided here on stackoverflow, however this code does not really work for me. It keeps copying all rows from "TXs" into "Convert" after it detects a change in "TXs".

```
function updateSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceValues = ss.getSheetByName("TXs").getRange("A2:M").getValues().filter(String);
  var targetSheet =  ss.getSheetByName("Convert");
  var targetRange =  targetSheet.getRange("A2:M");
  var targetColumn = targetRange.getColumn();
  var targetRow = targetRange.getRow();
  var targetValues = targetRange.getValues().filter(String);
  var diff = targetValues.showDif(sourceValues)
  
  targetRange.clearContent();
  targetValues = (diff && diff.length) ? targetValues.concat(diff) : targetValues;
   targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, targetColumn, targetValues.length, targetValues[0].length).setValues(targetValues);
 }

 Array.prototype.showDif = function (array) {
    var that = this;
    return array.filter(function (r) {
        return !that.some(function (x) {
            return r.join() === x.join();
        })
    })
}
```

I hope I explained it more or less understandable. Sorry in case I´ve used wrong terminology at some points, as I said: I´m a total newbie.

Many thanks in advance,
Jan

Here the link to my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1js11rdG6IWdfps00kuFaWk5VOP_Ve7ltvfdPWKlKVrA/